# State in a java.util.function.Function

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Suppose that I have a `class` which `implements` `java.util.function.Function`. The `Function` needs to know about a start date and end date **but** these will be constant throughout the lifetime of the function.

I'm considering implementing the `Function` with `private final` fields for the start and end dates, as the `apply` method doesn't require new values for them for each call. I feel that this will simplify my implementation but worry that this goes against the whole functional programming paradigm.

Is it reasonable to have immutable class members in a  `Function` when the values are required by the `apply` method but are constant throughout the lifetime of the `Function`?

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach.

> I feel that this will simplify my implementation but worry that this goes against the whole functional programming paradigm.

To solve this, you could implement a method, which gets your start and end date, and returns you a function. For example:

```
public static final Function<Object, Object> getDateF(final Date start, final Date end) {
  return input -> {
    // do something with start / end for your calculation
    final Object output = null;
    return output;
  };
}
```

Replace Object to whatever you need.

Comment: I'd like to add that at runtime this will evaluate to an object that implements `Function` which will have two fields for `start` and `end`, just like in Roberts suggestion. This in only shorter and prettier.

Comment: Having the `Function` implemented like a class, such as the one described in the question, makes it a little dangerous in that where the function is used, it's already been initialised and so the programmer doesn't realise it has dependencies on fields other than those passed into `apply`, unless they read the initialisation. This approach gets around that issue.